# Question related to IBM cloud pak for application certification question

Tags: docker, cloud, openshift, websphere, cloud-pak-for-data

I am preparing for IBM cloud pak for application certification and came across this question. What is the right answer.

A top level directory listing of an application stack contains the following:

README.md, stack.yaml,  image (directory) templates (directory)

Within the image directory are the following:

config (directory) project (directory) Dockerfile-stack

Based on the scenario above, where should a Solution Architect look

1. to understand the ***assets that are part of the application stack*** used in all applications?
2. to understand ***which endpoints are being used for readiness and liveness by applications*** created by the stack
3. look to understand ***the build process used to create a container of the application***?

Below are the options for each of the 3 questions above.

A.  In the templates directory

B.  In the image/project directory

C.  In the stack.yaml file

D.  In the image/Dockerfile-stack file

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in my opinion, it is now waste of time to do CP4Apps cert, as CP4Apps is now transformed to WebSphere Hybrid Edition and no longer has all these stack pieces included.

But looking at your question, just check these links and look into sample stack to learn details:

- [Customizing application stacks](https://kabanero.io/guides/working-with-stacks/)
- [Node.js Express Stack](https://github.com/appsody/stacks/tree/master/incubator/nodejs-express)

So my bet would be:

- 1 - probably A (dont know what they had in mind by saying assets)
- 2 - it can be found in app code or in deployment file so B
- 3 - build process is in Dockerfile so B

Comment: The above are 3 different questions with same options to select from. I am not seeing any certification details for WebSphere Hybrid Edition

Comment: There are no certification as it just was announced in January.